# Как настроить на Open VPN автоматическое подключение

Tags: windows, openvpn, configuration

Вводная - конфигурация создана и вручную подключается через GUI

Я или плохо прочитал документацию или сделал что-то не так. Можно конечно сделать ещё и через планировщик задач, но не думаю что это оптимальный способ.

Лог

> Thu Mar 23 09:17:26 2017 OpenVPN 2.4.0 x86_64-w64-mingw32 [SSL
>   (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [PKCS11] [AEAD] built on Jan 31 2017 Thu Mar 23
>   09:17:26 2017 Windows version 6.2 (Windows 8 or greater) 64bit Thu Mar
>   23 09:17:26 2017 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017, LZO
>   2.09 Thu Mar 23 09:17:27 2017 OpenSSL: error:02001005:system library:fopen:Input/output error Thu Mar 23 09:17:27 2017 OpenSSL:
>   error:2006D002:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:system lib Thu Mar 23
>   09:17:27 2017 OpenSSL: error:140AD002:SSL
>   routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file:system lib Thu Mar 23 09:17:27
>   2017 Cannot load certificate file C:\Program
>   Files\OpenVPN\config\client.crt Thu Mar 23 09:17:27 2017 Exiting due
>   to fatal error

Comment: https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/install.html?start=1 ищите раздел `Running OpenVPN as a Windows Service`